# include user data in query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I would like to query a table, which holds workflow events with the appr. user id. And instead of the user id, I would like to show the user name.

I have this model:

```
public class WorkflowEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public WorkflowStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public long WorkflowId { get; set; }
    public long DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the user model (it is the standard `IdentityUser`, I use Asp.Net Identity):

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int> 
{
    public string RealName { get; set; }
    public string AppTheme { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my query:

```
public IEnumerable<WorkflowEvent> WorkflowEvents(int DocumentId)
    {
        return DataContext.WorkflowEvents.Where(e => e.DocumentId == DocumentId).Include(e => e.User).OrderBy(e => e.EventDate);
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, I get following error on this: `System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid`. In the `WorkflowEvents` table, there is a foreign key on the `UserId`, of course.

Have you any idea, why do I get this error message? What goes wrong?

Comment: I'd check the database model, since you're overriding the default key type in `IdentityUser<int>`. See if your model's `int UserId` should be `int AppUserId`, also the navigation property `public AppUser User` should be enough. You don't neccessary need to define the key property in the model.

Comment: Just a thought, on your model the ```User``` property is Get only. What happens if you add the setter as well? EF might be constructing the ```WorkflowEvent``` and then trying to set the User and that could be getting in the way. I can't say for where sure but I recall something I came across discussing how relationships are built up on EF queries, and that ```Include``` runs a second query and then fixes up the relationships. @Sami might have the fix, but this is something simple to try if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Both Sami's and Nik's suggestions helped. I added the setter to the `AppUser`. And then I got the error, that the `AppUser` object isn't exists. This due to the fact, that I have in my app two datacontexts: one for the domain models and one for `Identity`. So, I just add this line of code to the domain data context:

```
    public DbSet<AppUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
```

And everything worked like a charm.